# Is it possible to install miktex and texlive on the same machine in linux?

Tags: miktex, texlive

Now, miktex is available for selected distributions of linux.  Is is possible to install miktex and texlive on the same machine without any problem? If yes, how? Can anybody who has done this share his/her experience?

Comment: You can do it, but you should only install more than one TeX distribution if you know how to work with PATHs and how to resolve dependencies if there are any (i.e. if you know your OS).

Answer (score 4):

As long as you don't run out of space on your harddisk, you can install even texlive *and* miktex.

But using one of them without running into trouble is something for experts. Let's say, miktex were installed on /usr/local/miktex and texlive in /usr/local/texlive.

OK, you could write pathes in your .profile to both, but comment out one or another. If you'd like to change, edit .profile, log out, log in again and proceed.

But miktex and texlive differ. A *.tex file you compiled with miktex might not compile with texlive due to different versions of a package or a document class.

So may advice is: Don't do it until you are an expert.

Comment: On windows it is easier, there you only need to change the path variable. Beside this: The fact that the systems differ is one of the reason why I have both. It helps a lot to track down errors if you can compare working with not-working compilations.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ha, on newer Windows versions. I remember that you had to reboot after a path change in earlier versions. However, OP is on Linux (which makes him an expert ?). And your error tracking abilities are so much above nearly anybody else' -- you really want newcommers to confuse things between MikTeX and TeXlive?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you only need to change the path on linux too

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, but usually you have pathes in your .profile and after a change there you have to log in again. That's what I meant. As far as I remember the texlive manual tells you to do that.

Comment: @KeksDose I change pathes locally in my editor. This never needed a reboot (at least I'm using this since 2012 and it works fine).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That worked in XP and earlier?

Comment: Sure. You could always locally change the path variable in a cmd-window, so the editor only needs to do the equivalent of `set path =XXX;%path% pdflatex .... `.

Comment: I wrote to Christian. He has made this addition to FAQ and sent me the link. https://miktex.org/faq/miktex-and-texlive. Thanks everybody!